# Problems with JQuery .get() -

Tags: javascript, jquery

on my site is a form which has multiple checkboxes with the same name:

```
<span class="selection"><input type="checkbox" name="product" value="Hard Enamel" />Hard Enamel</span>
<span class="selection"><input type="checkbox" name="product" value="Soft Enamel" />Soft Enamel</span>
<span class="selection"><input type="checkbox" name="product" value="Metal Relief" />Metal Relief</span>
<span class="selection"><input type="checkbox" name="product" value="Printed With Epoxy" />Printed With Epoxy</span>
```

In my Javascript, I assign these to a variable and have an onclick function using JQuery. With this I can still run JQuery functions no problem, e.g. `products.css("display","none")` works.

But when trying to select a particular checkbox within `products` it hits back with an error.

Here is my JS:

```
var products = $("input[name=product]").click(function(){selectProduct()});

products.get(0).css("display","none");
```

The above doesn't work, and I get the error `badges_calc.js:9TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'products.get(0).css("display","none")')`

How can I fix this? I'm rather beginner.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.get()` returns a raw DOM object.

You want `.eq(0)`, which returns a jQuery object with only one element.

Answer (score 2):

`get()` returns DOM element try use `eq` instead. DOM element does not have css method it is the jquery Object that has it. `eq(0)` will give you the first element in the collection as a jquery object.

```
products.eq(0).css("display","none");
```

And if you are really looking to hide the span along with the check box then use:

```
products.eq(0).closest('span').css("display","none");
```

otherwise it will leave the span with the text there itself, by just hiding the checkbox.

Comment: sorry mate, when i first looked i thought his was a couple seconds faster

Comment: @user1952067 But your tabs should have sorted based on first one right ans also you can check for the time by hovering on the date

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var products = $("input[name=product]");
products.click(function(){selectProduct()});
products.eq(0).css("display","none");
```

When you use `.get()` you will get a raw DOM element and cannot use jQuery's methods, so you cannot use `.css()`

Answer (score 0):

Use closest or parent to hide the selected input's parent.

```
var products = $("input[name=product]").click(function(){selectProduct(this)});

var items = [];
function selectProduct(self){
    $(self).closest('span').hide('slow');
    items.push($(self).val());
    console.log(items);
}
```